# Is it possible to add a menu bar to a widget

Tags: qt

I would like to add a QMenuBar to a window of my program (not the QMainWindow) from QtDesigner but I do not see this widget in there and it seems the only way to do this from designer is to use a mainwindow.  Would I absolutely need to create this QMenu by hand coding it.  Is it possible/ok to instead add a QMainwindow that is actually declared inside my main QMainwindow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a second instance of `QMainWidow` or make the widget which need to receive the menu bar inherit from it.

Comment: Yeah I am asking that in my question (if i'm clear enough).  More precisely I was asking if this is a safe thing to do or if it could create errors.

Comment: Just found out that you could also use `QLayout::setMenuBar( QWidget * )`.

Answer (score 0):

There is tricky way to add QMenuBar anywhere. You can add simple widget in designer and then edit your ui file with simple text editor. You can find your widget by name and replace "QWidget" with "QMenuBar". After that you can reload ui file in designer and work with QMenuBar same way as if was on QMainWindow

Answer (score -2):

Right click on widget in Object panel (where you see objects in tree view) and select Create Menu Bar.
That's it.

Comment: This is not an available option in Qt Designer.